# Track sales using UTM params

Tags: seo, google-analytics

I have a requirement to track visits to sales conversion using UTM parameters, here is the scenario:

Client will post multiple advertisement on several platform (newsletter, facebook, twitter etc), and track it using google analytic by making use of UTM parameters.

Here is the report types they are looking for

1. Track number of visitors per campaign from different source
2. Track visits to sales conversion rate (if user complete sign-up from the form)

For #1 google utm seems perfect, however for #2 i am not sure if we can send custom parameters in google analytic, such as if a visitor submitted a specific form and letting the report know that since the visitor signed up it must be recorded that this visit was converted to sale.

Is it possible using google analytic, if yes any pointer towards right direction is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One can send custom Dimensions and Custom Metrics to GA as an event. The sales workflow process is tracked to the actual sale the sale is an event. [Google Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide?hl=en)